# Check if jObject exists in json File - Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

how can I check if the Object 'Production' in my json-File exists in Powershell?

an extract of my json File:

```
[
  {
        "UID":  "x,
        "Office":  "xy",
        "Production":  "a"
    }
]
```

In this case the key "Production" does exist in the json File. But that is not always the case.

How can I check if it exists via Powershell? With `Get-Member`?

my approach:

```
$json = Get-Content "C:\file.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($item in $json) {
   if (Get-Member -InputObject $item.Production) {Write-Host "Production exists"}
   else {Write-Host "Production does not exist"}
}
```

THANKS!

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: It says that i does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the property exists by accessing the object's [`PSObject.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject), one of the many ways to validate could be using the `.Item(..)` method:

```
$json = '[{ "Production":  "Hello" }, { "OtherProp": "Nothing Here" }]' | ConvertFrom-Json
$count = 0
foreach($item in $json) {
    $index = 'Object {0}' -f $count++
    if($prop = $item.PSObject.Properties.Item('Production')) {
        "{0}: Production Exists and it's value is: '{1}'" -f $index, $prop.Value
    }
    else {
        "{0}: No property with name Production" -f $index
    }
}
```

You can also use the property name to index to the *NoteProperty Object* with the following syntax:

```
if($prop = $item.PSObject.Properties['Production']) {
```

The first object from the example Json has a property with Name **Production** and **Hello** as Value while the second object does have the specified property. Above would result in:

```
Object 0: Production Exists and it's value is: 'Hello'
Object 1: No property with name Production
```